# How to connect to Google Calendar API from a browser using a service account?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I am writing a Vue application (fully client based) that needs to access a Google Calendar API through a service account

- the service account is all set and works from Python or Go
- security is not a concern (the access secrets will be part of the JS code)

I tried to get a JWT via

```js
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library';

const credentials = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "Y",
    "private_key_id": "8...4",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII...Kag==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "X@Y.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "10...9",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/XX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

const calendarClient = new JWT({
    email: credentials.client_email,
    key: credentials.private_key,
    scopes: [ // set the right scope
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events',
    ],
});

console.log(calendarClient)
```

This yields an error

```
index.ts:29 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/agent-base/dist/index.js (index.ts:29:42)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3:50)
    at node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js (index.ts:7:1)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3:50)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js (gaxios.ts:33:1)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3:50)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js (index.ts:15:1)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3:50)
    at node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js (index.ts:8:1)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3:50)
node_modules/agent-base/dist/index.js @ index.ts:29
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js @ index.ts:7
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js @ gaxios.ts:33
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js @ index.ts:15
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js @ index.ts:8
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js @ googleauth.js:19
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js @ index.js:17
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/index.js @ index.js:16
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/abusiveexperiencereport/index.js @ index.js:17
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/index.js @ index.js:17
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/googleapis/build/src/googleapis.js @ googleapis.js:16
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js @ index.js:26
__require @ chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=7386d1fc:3
(anonymous) @ index.js:975
```

There does not seem to be references to this error in my searches so I am quite lost.

**My question**: is it possible to access to the Google Calendar API from the browser using a service account?

*Note: there is a [question with a similar name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201174/using-the-google-calendar-api-with-a-service-account-in-nodejs), but it deals with issues post-JWT creation.*

Comment: Client side javascript doesn't support services account

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo would you know if this is just a matter of "support" or whether there is a fundamental technical block? Since it is ultimately a HTTP call I am not sure what the barrier would be

Comment: security wise it would be a nightmare

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo - it depends on the risk profile. In my case, this is my application, for my personal use that assesses to my calendars. This could also be said of a backend application, all depends how it is used, isolated etc. As I mentioned in my question, security is not a concern (I anticipated that point)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** It is not possible to use Service accounts with client sided JavaScript.  It is not supported by Google's Oauth system.

## Reason

This is due to the security ramifications.  Weather or not you feel this is a security risk is moot.  Its not supported because **it is** a security risk.

You will need to switch to a server sided programming language if you want to use service account authorization.

If you do decided to switch languages, remember to configure domain wide delegation to your google workspace domain and remember to include the user for which you want to delegate.

Note. Service accounts only work with Google calendars though workspace domains not standard Gmail domains.

Comment: I still do not understand why **technically* they do not work - what is the difference between the calls from a backend and a browser client. The only difference I see could be CORS. As for security - sorry but whether something is secure or not comes from a risk assessment. Using a service account can be extraordinarily dangerous too (or not at all).

Comment: The issue is that if you view source in JavaScript your going to be able to see all the settings you need to use the service account.   Your going to be letting people use your service account to do what ever they want.   Your job is to keep your credentials secure,  client side JavaScript is not secure enough to use a service account.    Just switch to Node.js its not hard i may even have an example floating around if you need

Comment: Well, this is **my** application, for **my** usage - **nobody else** will be accessing it. Where is the risk? All the claims you mention must be backed by a risk profile - otherwise they are not very relevant in the void. (FYI I work in information security so this is an everyday topic). Also, the question was about whether it is possible to do that, not if there is a risk (and there is obviously one in typical cases)

Comment: Service accounts don't work with client sided JavaScript  <-- there is your answer then.

Comment: "Service accounts don't work with client sided JavaScript <-- there is your answer then" - thank you :) Do you know why, technically speaking? (I am asking seriously, I saw you were very fluent in Google API)

Comment: I don't work for Google so cant tell you why they don't support it.   Other then my opinion that it would be insecure because someone could view source on the browser and grab the information needed to use it.

Comment: you can probably make it work from the client code, just not using the Google library. Their library does not support this mode for security reasons, I think, not technical. If I may suggest, check out Aurinko.io; you can upload your service account key to your account and call Google API through Aurinko in a secure way (based on cookie).